# Getting incorrect answers

Tags: equation, modulo

I'm new to Python with three minor inquiries. Thank you.

1. Tried to solve this equation (last question of the three) and got the wrong answer based on me working it out by hand [Last question is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yAj0.png).
2. I could use some guidance on the simplest way to present the answer.
3. This other equation is also showing the wrong answer for a modulo - see before and after [Before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9fzc.png) [Modulo/After change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi7Qh.png).

Comment: The answer to #1 seems correct to me, what do you expect? And `-20 mod 6 = 4` seems to also be correct.

Comment: Thanks Taschi. The result of the modulo shouldn't it be -2?

Comment: No, not the way Python handles the modulo of negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you Taschi for the clarification.